# How to loop through columns to drag down formulas?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range defined by row 1-last row, and am trying to do the following:

1. Look at the last row IN EACH COLUMN (they should all be the same) and - if that cell is empty - drag down the formula from row 1 until the last row in that column (for example, if I'm on column A and my last row is row 10, I will assess if A10 is empty, and if it is, I will drag down the formula from A1 all the way down to A10)
2. Loop through columns A-M and repeat this process

I am having a hard time with this as I keep getting a "PREPARING FOR EXECUTION" message while debugging, and it doesn't ever run.

```
function dragformulas() {

    var sh2=SpreadsheetApp
        .getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("Inputs for Web App")
    var lastrow = sh2.getLastRow();

  for (var j=0; j < 14 ; j+1) {

    var emptyrange= sh2.getRange(lastrow, j+1, 1, 1);

  if (emptyrange.isBlank()) {

    var copyformulacell = sh2.getRange(1, j+1, 1, 1);
    var dragrange= sh2.getRange(1, j+1, lastrow - 1, 1);

    var getformula = copyformulacell.getFormulas();

    dragrange.setFormula(getformula);

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `=arrayformula()` to, basically, have your formula automatically populate to the last row without the need of a script?

Comment: This is part of a larger script, where I'm actually appending more and more rows to the sheet over time.

Comment: `var getformula = copyformulacell.getFormulas();` assings an array to getformula. setFormula requires a string not an array.

Comment: I tried doing GETCELL to pull just the formula on that cell, but I still get the same delay when trying to run it...

var copyformulacell = sh2.getRange(1, j+1, 1, 1).getCell(1,j+1);

Comment: just try removing the s from getFormulas

Answer (score 0):

I SIMPLIFIED THE CODE AND NOW IT WORKS. FOR FUTURE REFERENCE, HERE IT IS...

```
 function myFunction() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Looping columns");
  var lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
  var numrows = lastrow;
  var lastcol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var numcols = lastcol;
  var range = sh.getRange(1,1,numrows,numcols);
  sh.setActiveRange(range);

  return propagateFormulae(numrows, numcols, sh);

}

function propagateFormulae(rows, cols){

  for(var i=1;i<=cols;i++){
    for(var j=2;j<=rows;j++){
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Looping columns");
      if(sh.getRange(j,i).getValue().length == 0)
        sh.getRange(j-1,i).copyTo(sh.getRange(j,i));
      else{
        j=rows;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```